# Why does my fermented beet kvass taste bad?

Tags: fermentation

I took 4 medium beets, chopped them up in a medium dice, put the beets in a 1-gallon Pickl-It jar.  I added 1 ½ tablespoon unrefined sea salt, added filtered water to ½ inch below lid, and closed with an airlock.

I allowed this to ferment for 1 ½ weeks in darkness.  I then tasted it, and the taste was very bad, like an acidic fizzy vinegar.  I have tried this many times, and I keep getting this same result.

Any ideas on what Im doing wrong?

PS I found the recipe here http://bit.ly/1hdbx7S

Answer (score 6):

Given the recipe, that's exactly the sort of flavour I'd expect. I've never made this beverage, but I've made sauerkraut and it's done in an almost identical way except using cabbage instead of beets. The fermentation is bacterial, and lactobacilli play a predominant role. These bacteria produce lactic acid which is what makes sauerkraut sour, and presumably why your kvass is sour. The fizzy part is due to ongoing fermentation producing carbon dioxide.

I think the name "kvass" might be misapplied here. [Kvass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kvass) is used to describe a sort of beer made from bread. What you've made is much more like sauerkraut juice.

Comment: Kvass is more like a slightly alcoholic rye.... drink.